# Difference between orthogonal complement and Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Could someone explain what is the difference between these two? From my poor understanding they seem to do the same thing, given a set of vectors we find their corresponding orthogonal vectors. Maybe im just not understanding the usage of the terms.

Comment: Gram Schmidt is just a process to find the orthogonal components of a set of vectors.

Comment: So the orthogonal complement just refers to the name of the resulting orthogonal set obtained from the gram process?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Answer (score 3):

The Gram-Schmidt process takes a basis for a vector space and outputs an orthonormal basis for that space.  Moreover, this basis spans the same flags as the original one.

The orthogonal complement operator takes a subspace and outputs the subspace of all vectors orthogonal to every vector in that subspace.